# Assign category through a plugin

Tags: categories, plugins

I am importing data into Craft. I happen to know that the id for my desired category is 22. The category is not being saved.

Here is my code.

```
    $entry = new EntryModel(); 
    $entry->sectionId   = 3; // 3 is Episode Section
    $entry->enabled     = true;
    $entry->authorId    = 1;
    $entry->slug = $slug;
    $entry->postDate = $postDate;
    $entry->getContent()->title = $title;
    $entry->getContent()->body = $body;
    $entry->getContent()->summary = $summary;
    $entry->getContent()->metaDescription = $summary;
    $entry->showName[] = 22;
```

Where showName is the category handle of my category field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out. 1st, I added the getContent()

I changed

```
    $entry->showName[] = 22;
```

to

```
    $entry->getContent()->showName = 22;
```

I think the problem is that the category we had set up only allowed for a single value and I was responding with an array.

Someone please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Now that I have solved the problem of assigning a single category I find myself stumped when assigning multiple categories. How do I pass an array of category ids into getContent()->showName?

Comment: getContent()->showName = array(10,1468,14,15,16);